# How to launch a custom UIView as a Dialog iOS

Tags: ios, swift, dialog

I'm working on a Dialog for my iOS app, and have decided that the default boxes don't allow for the level of customization I am looking for.

So, I have created a view inside a storyboard. It is embedded in a view called `DialogBoxView` inside `DialogLayout.storyboard` with a view controller called `DialogLayoutViewController`.

In short, I want to be able to open the specific view *as* a Dialog. (Like this below.)

[image: Like this one]

But, as previously mentioned, I want the View inside the Storyboard to inflate as the dialog's layout.

What I need is a way to call into the ViewController handling the Storyboard [I can do this] and open the specific DialogBoxView inside.

See:

[image: My Hierarchy]

My Hierarchy

See:

[image: My Layout]

My Layout

Please note that I have browsed around a bit on Google, and nothing is useful. It is either outdated (OBJ-C) or not what I really need.

Additionally, is it possible just to (like in Android/Java) "inflate" the View layout as the Dialog's view?

Summary:

Can anyone give me an example on how to inflate a specific view (inside a Storyboard) as the dialog programmatically from the ViewController?

I'm still kinda new to Swift and iOS development in general, and I *have* come across some functions that *may* work, I just can't put them together in a way that actually works.

*NOTE:* I have found a way around custom layouts, but am still curious as to how this might work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Swift 5

Some time ago, I created one project similar: You can see in: https://github.com/MaatheusGois/custom-alert